# How to access AngularJS variable from template script

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, angularjs-scope

My controller:

```
$scope.totals = totals;
```

My template (works as expected for html injection):

```
{{totals}}
```

But what I need is to access the variable `totals` in a script in the template, like so:

```
<script>
  var totals = ????;
  // do stuff with totals
</script>
```

I've tried `$scope.totals`, `$totals`, `{{totals}}`, etc, with no avail. I would appreciate any insight, thanks!

EDIT:

The following is a jsfiddle of my controller and template. Inside of the template I'm wanting to insert a script that uses the `$scope.totals` variable.

http://jsfiddle.net/38CrC/

Comment: This helps http://stackoverflow.com/q/17960622/6521116

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OP Answer:

I ended up having to use a directive to find the value I wanted. In the controller that set the value I wanted to use I added a directive so that it looked like this:

```
'use strict';

angular.module('AdminApp')
  .controller('AdminEventsCtrl', function ($scope, collection) {
    $scope.totals = collection;
  }).directive('foo', function(){
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        link: function(scope, elem, attrs){
            //Use scope.totals here
        }
    }
});
```

In my template I had the declaration:

```
<div foo></div>
```

This gave me the ability to do what I needed with the variable totals.

Special thanks to @jvandemo for helping me arrive at this answer.

Answer (score 14):

First of all, the idea behind AngularJS is to avond situations like that.

In terms of AngularJS you woud probably be better off rethinking your application and use a directive to encapsulate the code you are currently writing in the script tags.

However, that being said, there is a way to access a scope like this:

```
var $element = $('#elementId');

var scope = angular.element($element).scope();
```

You can read the [documentation](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/angular.element) for more details.

But as said, it is not a recommended practice in most cases.

Hope that helps!

---

Update after OP posted jsFiddle:

I created a working jsFiddle for your convenience at http://jsfiddle.net/jvandemo/hYnBa/1/

Since your example has a simple `div` with an `ng-controller` attribute, you can access the scope like this:

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        var $element = $('div[ng-controller="AdminEventsCtrl"]');
        var scope = angular.element($element).scope();
        console.dir(scope);
    });
</script>
```

Here's what happens:

- You select the element (in this case by using jQuery)
- You wrap the element as an AngularJS element (exposing extra methods on the element)
- You call the `scope()` method on the element
- You can then access the scope properties e.g. `scope.totals`

Hope that helps!

Comment: From your question I get the following for scope:

    `Child {$id: "006", this: Child, $$listeners: Object, $parent:     
    Child, $$asyncQueue: Array[0]…}
    $$asyncQueue: Array[0]
    $$childHead: Child
    $$childTail: Child
    $$listeners: Object
    $$nextSibling: null
    $$prevSibling: null
    $$watchers: Array[7]
    $id: "006"
    $parent: Child
    this: Child
    __proto__: Child`

No where do I see the value that I want to use.

Comment: Make sure that you select an element that is bound to the scope you wish to retrieve. AngularJS builds a hierarchy of scopes and you need to select the right one. Your current sample code does not allow me to see what selector you would have to use. If you create a plnkr, I would gladly help you with that too.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/38CrC/  There's a fiddle of what I have to work with (minified of course). I hope this helps.

Comment: I added a working jsFiddle at http://jsfiddle.net/jvandemo/hYnBa/1/ and updated my answer with extra code for your convenience.

Comment: This ended up not working. I had to use a directive to get the value, as I could never find the correct scope for value I was trying to get. However, your answer led me in the correct direction, so thanks for your help.

Comment: You can just use `scope.totals` to access the data (see updated jsFiddle on http://jsfiddle.net/jvandemo/hYnBa/2/) but as suggested, using a directive is indeed a better and cleaner way in terms of AngularJS so your new code is definitely better. Glad to see you improved your code!

Comment: If debugInfo is disabled, and it should be in production, then you can't access the scope of angular element.