# Using AngularJS Values in JavaScript Function

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a function that calls some code using the Jcrop API that takes in some values to set aspect ratio. However, I need those values to come from a data connection for which I'm using Angular. So I need something like this:

```
<img src="sample.jpg" onclick="setAspectRatio({{valueToSet}});" />
```

But I get [this error](https://docs.angularjs.org/error/$compile/nodomevents) when trying to do it that way. If I do it this way:

```
<img src="sample.jpg" ng-click="setAspectRatio({{valueToSet}});" />
```

Then `valueToSet` actually evaluates, but I can't call it this way as `setAspectRatio()` isn't defined in any controller (it's a script on my page itself). This is mainly because it uses Jcrop and I didn't want to mix Jcrop with my Angular controller.

How can I accomplish what I'm trying to do here?

Answer (score 2):

You don't need the {{}} around the variable name. ng-click=setAspectRatio(valueToSet) should work.

Comment: OP said that the `setAspectRatio` function is not on the controller's $scope.

Comment: Yeah `setAspectRatio` has to be defined on the page itself because it uses Jcrop.

Comment: Ah, totally missed that. :( have you tried something along the lines of...

angular.element(document.querySelector('[ng-controller="controllerNameHere"]')).scope().variableName

Comment: Example... something like http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17960622/pass-angular-scope-variable-to-javascript