# How can I Pass data from an Angular Controller to JavaScript or to Paper.js

Tags: javascript, angularjs, paperjs

How can I Pass data from an Angular Controller to Paper.js via JavaScript ?

This is a question nearly identical to this previous question:

[Pass Angular scope variable to Javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17960622/pass-angular-scope-variable-to-javascript?answertab=active#tab-top)

The first answer to the previous question would not work for me (I show it below) and I dont clearly understand the second answer(which is a workaround too)

> edit: I figured out a bit cheesy solution that allows passing values
>   from Angular to Javascript:  I know it isn't the Angular way and
>   likely has some other shortcomings (and I'd be more than happy to have
>   them called out)-- I'm showing it in an answer below)

Is a new answer available now, two years later?

Maybe there is a paper.js  direct method? (earlier question didn't pertain to paper.js)

My code and circumstance details below:

```
// snippet frome angular controller named "colorSelector"

 $scope.xCoor = image.xCoor; 
 $window.xCoor = image.xCoor; //hoped this would work but doesn't


//angular works fine in the html


  <p> {{description}}</p>
  <p>{{xCoor}} is the X coordinate, {{yCoor}}</p>
```

edit: removed ng-repeat wrapper as it didn't apply directly to question.(second edit cleaned that up more)

```
//paper.js successfully has access to global JS variables, but
//I cannot get angular information into the JavaScript variables
<script type="text/javascript">
  targetX = 250; targetY=270; //hardwired works (I'm only using x for example)

  // targetX = {{image.xCoor}} doesn't work (no surprise)
  // targetX = window.xCoor // I thought this might work? but it doesn't
  // suggestion below from earlier S.O. question doesn't work for me
  // targetX =  angular.element(document.querySelector('[ng-controller="colorSelector"]')).scope().xCoor
    </script>

<!-- paper.js section below -->
<script type="text/paperscript" canvas="myCanvas">
    //below works if variables are set above
    var target = new Path.Circle({
      center: [targetX, targetY],
      radius: 10,
      strokeColor: "white"
    });
</script>
```

If the "workaround" way of the second answer to the previous question still works, could someone flesh it out a bit for me? (they suggested inserting a string with script tags in it?)

Comment: I think the problem is in the order of execution, you need to delay paperscript execution until variables are set by your angular app. One more thing, in the controller you get the value from 'image' but it seems you have an array 'images'

Comment: Appreciate the thoughts.  My actual use case involves changing the canvas one picture at a time.   I left the "image in images" in this example as that is how I created a menu of thumbnails where upon a click on one would call an angular function which changes the present image.   The way this particular paper.js tool works it pulls the image from an image tag id onto the canvas. My goal is to use that Angular function to change the x and y coords of a circle overlay on the image to the stored values for each separate image.

Comment: -bit more: The canvas image does change when the angular function is called however,  it does take a second action of mousing over the canvas to display the new photo(the angular function causes the last to disappear, blur makes the new one visible on actual canvas).   Just including that as it may suggest timing as you suspect.  A second question I might want to ask (but one at a time?) is how to force a paper.js function to fire triggered by something inside an angular function.

Comment: could you provide a sample on plunker

Comment: I'm having a hard time getting this plunker working with angular and the canvas .. I'm sure I'll fix it soon.  Maybe the partial code would let you see where I was going better.  http://plnkr.co/edit/AS4fZ6lQFhUO2ASknElG?p=preview

Comment: I figured out another work-around but I don't think it is the correct Angular.js solution.  I used angular to put a value into a hidden-off-screen element with a named id like (id="x-id") for each value, then I set variable values in a javascript script using var targetX = num(getElementById("x-id").html) .  There was also a delay issue with paper.js unless I put that within paper.js canvasInitialization function I wrote.  (I still wish I could call that function within paper.js with the ng-click but... again that's a separate question)

Answer (score 0):

I figured out a simple work-around(not sure why it took so long) I know it isn't the Angular way and likely has some other shortcomings (and I'd be more than happy to have them called out)

```
// un-shown angular module defines $scope.xCoor

<div id="xCoor" class="hide-me-offscreen">
  {{x-coor}}
</d>

<script type="text/javascript" >
  var targetX = num(getElementById("x-coor").html)
</script>
```