# How to access scope angularjs from javascript?

Tags: angularjs

I have the same issue with this post [Pass Angular scope variable to Javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17960622/pass-angular-scope-variable-to-javascript) . But I can't achive my solution with their answers.

**My Angular Controller**

```
angular.module('App').controller('HomeController', [
    '$rootScope', '$scope', '$state', '$timeout', 'ReportService', 'MsgService',
    function($rootScope, $scope, $state, $timeout, ReportService, MsgService) {

        $scope.$on('$viewContentLoaded', function() {
            console.log('HomeController');
            $scope.get_locations();
        });

        // get locations
        $scope.get_locations = function() {
            var data = {};
            // call http get to my api
            MsgService.get_all_locations(data, function(response) {
                if (response.code == 1) { // success
                    $scope.locations_array = response.data; // data that I want to access to script
                } else {
                    alert(response.message);
                }
            });
        }
    }
]);
```

**My Html**

```
<div id="map" ng-controller="HomeController">{{locations_array}}</div> // {{locations_array}} scope have the result that I want
<script type="text/javascript">

$(document).ready(function() {
    var data = $('[ng-controller="HomeController"]').scope().$parent.locations_array;
console.log(data); // underfined

    //var $element = $('#map');
   // var scope = angular.element($element).scope();
   // console.dir(scope.$parent.locations_array); // underfined
});

</script>
```

I tried access from browser develop tool then It can access scope. But My code can't access this.

[image: Chorme develop tool]

How to solve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The immediate problem here is a timing issue - you are trying to read the `locations_array` value off the scope *long before* the value is populated.

The sequence of events is something like this:

1. `ready` event for document triggers, and before Angular has even thought about starting, your inline JS code runs, trying to read the value from the scope, which doesn't exist yet.
2. Angular bootstraps your Angular application in response to the document's `ready` event (this may be before #1, depending on the order of scripts on the page). This will call the `HomeController` constructor, that only sets up a listener for the `$viewContentLoaded` event.
3. The `$viewContentLoaded` event gets broadcast, and you initiate an asynchronous request for the locations.
4. When that returns with the locations some time later, it populates them on the scope.

### Don't rely on `.scope()`

In addition to the timing issues, there is another major problem with your solution - it relies on the debug information being included by AngularJS. Obviously, it is by default, but it is possible to [disable this debug information](https://code.angularjs.org/snapshot/docs/guide/production) for significant performance gains in production.

If someone else comes along, possibly after you have left, and tries to disable debug information to improve performance or for some other reason (it is a recommended practice in production), it will **stop `.scope()` from working**.

So by relying on `.scope()`, you are making it so that disabling debug info, a best practice and performance booster, is not possible now or in the future for your app, because it will break things. And it won't be at all obvious to that developer that it would break anything.

So relying on `.scope()` for anything other than debugging should always be a very last resort.

### So what do I do instead?

Like I mentioned, this is a timing problem - you need to wait until the locations are eventually loaded before running code that relies on them.

Luckily, we have many options in JS to deal with asynchronous values - callbacks, promises, RxJS observables, etc. Pick your favourite.

#### Example: using a global promise

In your controller, create a promise on the global scope (icky, but it needs to be outside Angular somewhere), and resolve that promise with the location data when it is loaded.

```
var resolveLocations;
window.locationsPromise = new Promise(function (resolve) { 
    resolveLocations = resolve;
});
angular.module('App').controller('HomeController', [
    '$rootScope', '$scope', '$state', '$timeout', 'ReportService', 'MsgService',
    function($rootScope, $scope, $state, $timeout, ReportService, MsgService) {

        $scope.$on('$viewContentLoaded', function() {
            console.log('HomeController');
            $scope.get_locations();
        });

        // get locations
        $scope.get_locations = function() {
            var data = {};
            // call http get to my api
            MsgService.get_all_locations(data, function(response) {
                if (response.code == 1) { // success
                    resolveLocations(response.data); // resolve the promise
                    $scope.locations_array = response.data; // data that I want to access to script
                } else {
                    alert(response.message);
                }
            });
        }
    }
]);
```

Then, your normal (non-angular) javascript (which needs to run after your Angular javascript file is loaded) could use that promise to do something with the data when available:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

$(document).ready(function() {
    window.locationsPromise.then(function (locations_array) {
        console.dir(locations_array);
        // do something with the data
    });
});

</script>
```

### There is probably a better way

Without knowing why you think you need access to this data outside of Angular, it's hard to say for sure, but there are likely other better ways of handling the interplay between Angular code and other Javascript code that depends on it.

Maybe you create a directive to integrate a jQuery plugin, or another service, or whatever, but since AngularJS code is just normal JS, there is no need to think of them as separate from each other. You just have to get the timing right so you have the data available. Good luck!

Comment: excellent explain!!. But this way can "dirty". 

Can I use localstorage instead of?. After I can get data from js. 
Create directive also the better solution.