# Pass angularJs variable to javascript Variable

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-scope

I have Angularjs variable that I want to pass in javascript variable. 
I found solution
 [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17960622/pass-angular-scope-variable-to-javascript) 
so it didn't work. My code :

```
<script>
var demo=angular.module('demo', []);
demo.controller('metrics', function($scope, $http) {
$http.get('http://localhost:8080/metrics').then(function(response) 
    {
     $scope.metrics = response.data;            
    });
    });
</script>

<div ng-controller="metrics">
<p>{{metrics}}<p>
</div>
<script>
var e = angular.element(document.querySelector('[ng-controller="metrics"]')); 
var e1 = e.scope().metrics ; 
alert(e1)   
</script>
```

I got result from **{{metrics}}**  but  **e1**  didn't return something. 
Thanks for your help.

Comment: Your issue is *timing*. `$scope.metrics` will be populated quite a bit later than you're trying to get it. It's a bad idea to poke around the innards of Angular like this anyway; you should angularify that bit of Javascript there; what exactly are you trying to do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From your current code, by the time the `JS` code executes, it will not contain `metrics` data.

The `JS` code should be written in the `then` response of the API call,

If you do that, the `JS` code will be called after the `metrics` gets a value.

```
var demo=angular.module('demo', []);
demo.controller('metrics', function($scope, $http) {
   $http.get('http://localhost:8080/metrics').then(function(response) 
    {
       $scope.metrics = response.data;            
       var e = angular.element(document.querySelector('[ng-controller="metrics"]')); 
       var e1 = e.scope().metrics ; 
       alert(e1);
    });
});
```

Comment: Of course, this does *not* actually "pass the value to Javascript"; and since you're doing your work in the callback, there's absolutely no need to do the song and dance with `document.querySelector` and so on either, just `alert(response.data)` would do.

Comment: @deceze, the questioner is just trying to pass the result into a `javascript variable`. I know that the result is direct. But as he is eager to pass to js variable using Javascript, I just solved the issue he is facing. As far as the question is considered, my answer is correct. No need to Downvote it.

Answer (score 1):

angular.element() is a function in angular to get a raw DOM

if you want to get a particular `<p>` then assign id attribute on it

with that raw DOM, you can add attribute, add classes or else ([check this link for more info](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/function/angular.element))

but if you want to do something with `metrics` then just use `$scope.metrics` after you get it from `$http`

```
<div ng-controller="metricsCtrl">
  <p id="metric">{{metrics}}<p>
</div>

<script>
  var demo=angular.module('demo', []);
  demo.controller('metricsCtrl', function($scope, $http) {
  $http.get('http://localhost:8080/metrics').then(function(response) 
      {
       $scope.metrics = response.data;

       // you can do whatever with $scope.metrics here
       console.log($scope.metrics);

      });
  var e = angular.element(document.querySelector('#metric'));
  console.log(e);
  e.addClass('some-class');     // here p will be <p class="some-class" id="metric">{{metrics}}<p>
  });
</script>
```