# How to pass of angular $scope variable to JavaScript normal variable

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-scope

Here is my Angular $scope.variable.

```
$scope.users = {
                id : '',
                fullName : '',
                email : '',
                profile_picture_url : ''
            }

            $scope.comments = {
                commentId : '',
                created_by_current_user : '',
                created_by_admin : '',
                user_has_upvote : '',
                creator : '',
                fullName : '',
                content : '',
                created : '',
                modified : '',
                upvote_count : '',
                profile_picture_url : '',
                pings : '',
                parent : '',
                uniqueId : '',
                postId : ''

            }
```

Im just getting the array of objects from the HTTP service and storing as angular variable. Here is my angular controller

```
$scope.getByPost = function(postId) {
                console.log('getpost')
                $scope.user = $cookieStore.get('currentApp');
                console.log($scope.user.uniqueId);
                $scope.getUsers();
                appService.getUserByPost($scope.user.uniqueId, postId)
                        .then(function(data) {
                            console.log("Comments" + data)
                            $scope.comments = data;
                        });
            };

            $scope.getUsers = function() {
                console.log('getpost')
                appService.fetchAllUsers().then(function(data) {
                    console.log("Users" + data)
                    $scope.users = data;
                }, function(error) {
                    console.log('Error ' + error)
                })
            };
```

Now I need to pass these variables to another normal JavaScript file for the DOM Operation. I did like this.

```
 var dom_el = document.querySelector('[ng-controller="appController"]');
       var ng_el = angular.element(dom_el);
       var ng_el_scope = ng_el.scope();
       var commentsArray = ng_el_scope.comments;
       var usersArray = ng_el_scope.users;
```

Not working. please tell me to solve this.

Comment: It depends on whether the dom has been created or not before you query it. in your case, it seems it is not

Comment: In Angular, if you would like to share the variable across the application, then better to keep it in Angular service or factory and use it where needed

Comment: have you tried this solution in stack http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17960622/pass-angular-scope-variable-to-javascript/#answer-17963609

Comment: @k185 Yes this is what i tried but it doesn't working. getting undefined value.

Comment: what are you trying to accomplish with this DOM operation?  why is it something that angular can't manage through it's normal bindings?

Comment: just use a service. Easier, more, maintainable and testable

Answer (score 1):

savethe value in your current controller to $rootscope like this  $rootscope.users = data;
use $rootscope.requiredValue=$rootscope.users; in other angular js page .

Answer (score 0):

Try to use `window.onload`, like:

```
window.onload=function(){
       var dom_el = document.querySelector('[ng-controller="appController"]');
       var ng_el = angular.element(dom_el);
       var ng_el_scope = ng_el.scope();
       var commentsArray = ng_el_scope.comments;
       var usersArray = ng_el_scope.users;
}
```

Or you can try to with `setInterval` because maybe your `js` code is running before `angular` finalize completely

Answer (score 0):

Try using like this:

Declare the JavaScript function as below

```
window.sample = function(comments)
{
 // do something
}
```

call this function in success callback

```
window.sample(data)
```