# how can I get a value from controller{angularJS} to script{js}

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm working angularJs and in the controller

```
vm.decodedData
```

when I display it in the HTML it's works but how can I get it's value to a script 'js'
I've been tried a lot of method but all of them gave me undefined 
like this issue [enter link description here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17960622/pass-angular-scope-variable-to-javascript)

please any advice will be appreciated

Answer (score 0):

You need to get the scope object of any of the elements in the HTML and then you can access the variables there.
although it is not advisable to do it, you can get the reference of the **body** using **angular.element** and then access the scope object using scope()

```
angular.module("app", []).controller("ctrl", function($scope){
  $scope.name = "Someone";
});            

    <script>
      $(function(){
        alert("Name from the Angular Scope is '" + angular.element("body").scope().name + "'");
      })
    </script>
```

Plunker
https://run.plnkr.co/UNTAqNTRpIcfRaAv/