# How to use a route param in an Angular page?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a page, which should be located at the address `http://localhost:8080/#/edit/someId`, where `someId` is the ID of the object to edit.

In order to do this, I wrote following route:

```
angular.module('myapp', [ 'ngRoute' ]).config(function($routeProvider,
$httpProvider) {
    $routeProvider.when('/', {
        templateUrl : 'projects.html',
        controller : 'projects'
    }).when('/edit/:id', {
        templateUrl : 'edit.html',
        controller : 'edit'
    })
    [...]
    .otherwise('/');
    $httpProvider.defaults.headers.common['X-Requested-With'] =
        'XMLHttpRequest';
})
[...]
.controller('edit', function($scope, $http, $routeParams) {
    $scope.projectid = $routeParams.id;
    console.log("projectid in handler: " + $routeParams.id);
    var projectid = $routeParams.id;
});
```

`edit.html` looks like this:

```
<div ng-show="authenticated">
    <div id="cesiumContainer"></div>
    <div class="toolbar-left">
        [...]
    </div>
    <script>

        var mode = 'nothing';
        var viewer = "undefined";

        console.log("projectid: " + projectid);

        // I need projectid here to initialize the Cesium viewer.

        if (typeof Cesium !== "undefined") {
            startup(Cesium, projectid);
        } else if (typeof require === "function") {
            require(["Cesium", projectid], startup);
        }
    </script>
</div>
<div ng-show="!authenticated">
    <p>Please login.</p>
</div>
```

When I enter `http://localhost:8080/#/edit/someId` in the browser,

1. the message starting with `projectid in handler:` (defined in the route) is not displayed in the log and
2. `projectid` is undefined in `edit.html`.

How can I change my code so that when I enter `http://localhost:8080/#/edit/someId`, `someId` is available inside the `script` block in `edit.html`?

Comment: Similar question over here - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17255728/how-to-access-angularjs-variable-from-template-script

Comment: this code belongs in a directive

Comment: @charlietfl Please submit your comment as an answer and I'll accept it.